# Improve webview performance for canvas animations without crosswalk on android 4.4

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, ionic-framework, android-webview

I have been working on a hybrid game which works fine on the android version 5 and 6. However, on android version 4.4 (and below possibly), the performance is terrible as I only get an FPS of 30. To make sure that it is not my game that results in poor performance, I tried to simply animate a circle which just moves left and right and still got an FPS of 30. Is there anything that I can do to improve the FPS then?

I am using Ionic to create my apps and I don't want to use crosswalk because it will increase the size of my game from about 3mb to 20 or 25 mb and there will be two different apk versions to deal with. Besides, the performance is slow only on older android version.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?